# Elastic Search exact match query with wildcard search for multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I have elastic search data store like below, and I need to write multi search ES query through these data with exact match and exact match + *(wildcard)

```json
[
  {
    "id": "123",
    "name": "test123 abc bct",
    "externalObj": {
      "id": "abc 123"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "124",
    "name": "test124 abc bct",
    "externalObj": {
      "id": "abc 124"
    }
  }
]
```

currently i have written query like below,

```json
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": [
        "name^5",
        "id",
        "externalObj.*"
      ],
      "query": "(test124 abc)",
      "default_operator": "AND"
    }
  }
}
```

Above query is working fine with exact match but I need to get the data for partial search and maximum relevant score for the response as well. that thing doesn't work with this query.

e.g: "query": "test124 ab"

Can anyone help me out for above problem ?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options to achieve what you want. You can choose one of them to use:

1. Set `default_operator` to `OR` (or just simply remove it since the default value is `OR`).

```json
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": [
        "name^5",
        "id",
        "externalObj.*"
      ],
      "query": "test124 a"
    }
  }
}
```

2. Change your query into `test124 a*`

```json
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": [
        "name^5",
        "id",
        "externalObj.*"
      ],
      "query": "test124 a*",
      "default_operator": "AND"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: with your suggestion exact match is working fine and partial match is also working fine for one scenario

it is working for "test124 abc*" but not for "test124 ab*"

Comment: That's strange. Both work fine for me. Did you keep your `default_operator` as `AND` when you try `test124 ab*`?

Comment: yes if we remove default_operator: "AND" it is getting unnecessary results with correct objects and also without having correct sorting order for the query input that we have given

Comment: simply I want to get result of "test124 abc bct" for "query": "test124 a"

Comment: I updated my answer with the example queries. Please try them. For both options, I get back `test124 abc bct`.

Comment: If you don't remove the `default_operator` or don't change your query, then I don't think you can get the result you want.